Umbraco 13 - Is Member in Role/MemberGroup?
I am working on an Umbraco 13 site, which is using members and member groups.
Within a template, I want to be able to determine if the current member is in a certain member group.  The goal is to only show certain content within the template to certain member group(s).
I was hoping there would be a method like:
member.IsInRole("myGroup");

but I haven't been able to find anything.
I know I could create my own method by utilizing IMemberService > GetAllRoles(int memberId) and checking against the list.
I am surprised that there isn't a method built in somewhere.  Does anyone know if I am missing it or does it just not exist?

There is no such method as IsInRole("myGroup") but there are similar ones that you can use.
If you want to use the IMemberService, then GetMembersByGroup(string memberGroupName) is what you can use (you then need to add a little code to understand whether your member is in the members list.
/// <summary>
///     Gets all Members within the specified MemberGroup name
/// </summary>
/// <param name="memberGroupName">Name of the MemberGroup</param>
/// <returns>
///     <see cref="IEnumerable{IMember}" />
/// </returns>
IEnumerable<IMember> GetMembersByGroup(string memberGroupName);

Alternatively, you can use IMembersipRoleService and GetMembersInRole(string roleName) or FindMembersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch, StringPropertyMatchType matchType = StringPropertyMatchType.StartsWith) methods to understand whether a member is in a role.
IMembersipRoleService - all existing methods:
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models.Membership;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Persistence.Querying;

namespace Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services;

public interface IMembershipRoleService<out T>
    where T : class, IMembershipUser
{
    void AddRole(string roleName);

    IEnumerable<IMemberGroup> GetAllRoles();

    IEnumerable<string> GetAllRoles(int memberId);

    IEnumerable<string> GetAllRoles(string username);

    IEnumerable<int> GetAllRolesIds();

    IEnumerable<int> GetAllRolesIds(int memberId);

    IEnumerable<int> GetAllRolesIds(string username);

    IEnumerable<T> GetMembersInRole(string roleName);

    IEnumerable<T> FindMembersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch, StringPropertyMatchType matchType = StringPropertyMatchType.StartsWith);

    bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwIfBeingUsed);

    void AssignRole(string username, string roleName);

    void AssignRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames);

    void DissociateRole(string username, string roleName);

    void DissociateRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames);

    void AssignRole(int memberId, string roleName);

    void AssignRoles(int[] memberIds, string[] roleNames);

    void DissociateRole(int memberId, string roleName);

    void DissociateRoles(int[] memberIds, string[] roleNames);

    void ReplaceRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames);

    void ReplaceRoles(int[] memberIds, string[] roleNames);
}


I was aware of these, but reluctant to use them because these MemberGroups will eventually have a large number of users.
I will go the route of looking up the roles for the Member and testing for the group I want to verify.

Glad my answer has helped you to make your final decision. Please remember to upvote the useful answers and accept the correct answers.

Umbraco members are created using ASP.NET Core Identity, so you can check if the current member is in a certain group or role directly through the Identity UserManager service.
In classes, you need to inject the UserManager<MemberIdentityUser> service in your constructor:
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly UserManager<MemberIdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IMemberManager _memberManager;

    public MyClass(UserManager<MemberIdentityUser> userManager, IMemberManager memberManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _memberManager = memberManager;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(string roleOrGroupName)
    {
        if (!_memberManager.IsLoggedIn())
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(false);
        }

        var currentUser = await _memberManager.GetCurrentMemberAsync();

        return await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(currentUser, roleOrGroupName);
    }

}

In Razor views, you can access the UserManager<MemberIdentityUser> service through the @inject directive:
@using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Security
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<MemberIdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<MemberIdentityUser> UserManager
@inject IMemberManager MemberManager

@if (MemberManager.IsLoggedIn())
{
    var currentUser = await MemberManager.GetCurrentMemberAsync();
    var roleOrGroupName = "myGroup";
    var isInRole = await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(currentUser, roleOrGroupName);
    
    if(isInRole){
        <!-- do something -->
    }
}

https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/fundamentals/data/members#technical
